# Semantic-ui when does one need to import/link components individually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, semantic-ui

If one imports all semantic.js and semantic.css files, when does one also need to import .js and .css files for individual semantic components?  Or are these individual semantic-ui component files only necessary when you want to keep things lightweight and only import the components you're using?

I've had to do import files individually for [table-sorting](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-tablesort) before. I got the impression this was because this functionality hadn't been included as formally as other components.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `semantic.js` and `semantic.css` then all components are included. Some complain that sizes of those files are too large to be used for a few components that they want to use, so you can opt for loading components individually instead. So that's an either-or, but not both